# Are IDEs really worth it?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

Are IDEs always a Good Thing(tm)? I used to use only jEdit, but a while back switched to NetBeans, mostly because of the GUI Builder and the NetBeans Platform (I'm mostly a Java programmer). While I am a lot more productive with it, it feels less flexible and I often find myself hacking some things in jEdit again (Scala in particular because the NetBeans Scala plugin is really buggy). All the behind-the-scenes stuff usually works great, but occasionally the way NetBeans does it is just inconvenient and there is no easy way to change it.

So while I'd assume most people are happy with IDEs because they make you more productive, are they really all they are made out to be?

Comment: Yeah, they're better for everything! No, all you ever need is [Vim|Emacs|...|notepad|I switch bits with my pinky] - voting to close as subjective. Maybe try http://programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: As you say, IDEs help you be more productive. Is there a good reason to be less productive? IDEs also help you produce better quality code. If you found the netbeans plugin to be really buggy, did you try a commercial IDE like IntelliJ (which atleast has good support)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on who you ask!  Seriously, everyone has their preference as to whether to use an IDE or not.  I personally do not for most things, except for Visual Studio with C#.  I believe that IDEs definitely have their good qualities, but they are simply not for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned before, you can do your development in a text editor, *and in your break, go mow the lawn with your teeth*...

In general, they are there to help you, make you more productive, as you said. If the IDE you use does not work for you, get something else.

Answer (score 1):

A good IDE is generally a great aid in terms of productivity, as it can:

- improve the navigation in your code with features like "go to declaration" and "find references" (essential!),
- speed up coding by providing code completion and highlighting errors during typing,
- allow you to run and debug (and, say, synchronize the project  via version control) from a single place,
- finally - write a lot of code (i.e. boilerplate code like class and method stubs) for you, so you don't have to waste time typing untrivial things.

There's more, but the above is what's the most important to me.